# Filter multiple columns using single slicer in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new in power bi. I am creating a basic tabular report in power bi. But the catch is I have multiple dates columns in the dataset (For Eg. productvalidfrom,productvalidto,ordervalidfrom,ordervalidto). And I want to filter these columns with a single date selection.
If I select 2021-09-01 then condition for filter will be
**2021-09-01>=productvalidfrom and 2021-09-01<productvalidto and 2021-09-01>=ordervalidfrom and 2021-09-01<ordervalidto**
and need to all the columns from the dataset. No summarization.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to implement this before. You will need to add a data table to your data sources. Then you will want to create relationships between the dates in your data and the date table. Only one of them will be active relationships, the rest will be inactive. Then, your slicer will use the date from your newly created date table.

This [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Need-Slicer-s-to-Filter-Multiple-Date-Columns-on-Single-Table/m-p/563582) should be able to guide you through the build.